# Extra column when migrating Sybase databases to single SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, migration, sybase, ssma

I'm trying to use Microsoft's [SQL Server Migration Assistant for Sybase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh302816%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) ('SSMA') to migrate multiple Sybase databases (that have the same schema) to a single SQL Server database.

All of the tables in the new SQL Server database will have an extra column `project_id`, which should have a fixed value depending on which Sybase database data is being migrated from.

I've migrated the schema using SSMA, and then created the new columns in SSMS. But I the new columns aren't visible in SSMA, and I can't see any way to achieve what I want to do.

How can I migrate data from each of the Sybase databases whilst utilising the extra `project_id` column?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out SSMA just ignores any extra columns you create after migrating the schema - so I could [set the default for the `project_id` columns](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/73277/45080) before migrating data from each Sybase database and have them populated with those defaults.